# InDesign: how to import multiple text files, each in its own box

Tags: adobe-indesign, import

Any way to import a series of text strings (for example, from a spreadsheet), so when imported each string gets a separate text box?

(I know how to import multiple text files--what I'm trying to do is import multiple strings of text from one file--but have each string get its own text box.)

Comment: What you call "strings" is quite unclear. How do you distinguish them? A separator? (tab, return...) A cell? I have the strong feeling that data merging  process is what you need, but you should clarify your request.

Answer (score 5):

- When importing all the text files or some of them > drag to create the import frame and without releasing the mouse:
- Press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to increase the grid number of columns
- Press <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to reduce the grid number of columns
- Press <kbd>Top Arrow</kbd> to increase the grid number of rows
- Press <kbd>Bottom Arrow</kbd> to reduce the grid number of rows
- Import

Next import, if pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows, Indesign will remember the last used grid parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Danielillo, but I need each each piece of text to end up in a separate text frame